# Google Calendar API Code 403: "The request is missing a valid API key."

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

So I am working on a script that gets data from a google sheets document and then uses the data to create a new google calendar event. But I get this error when running the script:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I tried updating the tokens but that didn't work, so I went through the internet and someone said I have to share the calendar with the google api console email which I didn't find and then I saw someone commented that that was disabled a year ago or so. Any Ideas why I don't have permission to my own calendar??

Edit: Also I have oauth to authorize myself so I shouldn't need an API Key right?

Eidt: here is my code, but I don't think that the problem is related to the code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import re

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of the kitconcept Holiday spreadsheet.
SPREADSHEET_ID = '<YOUR SPREADSHEET ID>'
RANGE_NAME = '<YOUR SHEET RANGE>'

# The ID of the kitconcept Calender.
CALENDAR_ID = '<YOUR CALENDAR ID>'


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google APIs."""

    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        calendarService = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        sheetsService = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = sheetsService.spreadsheets()
        result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])

        if not values:
            print('No data found.')
            return
        
        last_content = 0
        for row in values[2:]: # [2:] jumps to the second row in table
            if row[1] and row[2]:
                last_content += 1

                # Convert the date from Sheets into a date format that Calendar can reed
                calendarStartDate = "-".join(row[1].split(".")[::-1]) # [::-1] = .reverse(...)
                calendarEndDate = "-".join(row[2].split(".")[::-1])

                # Error handling: Remove all non-digit characters
                startDate = re.sub("[^\d\-]", "", calendarStartDate)
                endDate = re.sub("[^\d\-]", "", calendarEndDate)
                
        event = {
            'summary': 'Jonas Holidays',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': f'{startDate}',
                'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': f'{endDate}',
                'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin',
            },
        }

        event = calendarService.events().insert(calendarId=CALENDAR_ID, body=event).execute()
        print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))

    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

So, I was facing a similar problem while using it with OAuth2,
In my case the main thing I was doing wrong was scopes.

Google Calendar API has different scopes, which is like consent to access data, the default scope is Name, Email and stuff. For Calendar you need to add calendar scopes.

[Checkout scopes here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/auth)

Also, you can try out Google OAuth Playground and play around with different scopes and APIs